# How to analyze and decide whether used or not in sfdc.com?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I am on-boarded into a project where there are existing Apex Class, Apex Trigger, Aura Component Bundle, Custom Object, Lightning Component, Visualforce Component, and Visualforce Pages.

I am given a task to find out which of there components are currently being used in the sfdc.com system.

Should I start to go through the functional requirement documents first and understand how the system is and then check the code?

Or is there any tool which will help me in showing which sfdc.com components are being used and which are not being used?
Does show dependencies button help in this regard?

Also, for the apex class components which are being used how do I decided from where to start writing the test classes?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question but might be better for https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, your problem isn't really a specific coding issue...

Start with running built-in tools that should give you some degree of overview:

- Setup -> Storage Usage (so you'll see which objects have 0 records)
- Setup -> Optimizer (produces a massive PDF but good overview of over-configured areas which might be maintenance pain, users who don't log in too often, unused reports...)
- (At end of Optimizer report you should have bunch of resources / links for example to tool that analyses usage of custom fields, how many % are actually populated)
- Setup -> Lightning Experience Transition Assistant -> Get Started -> Discover Phase -> Evaluate... -> Check Readiness. Horrible, I know. But will tell you which Visualforce pages were accessed most recently. Or which buttons aren't on page layouts so if people can't click to get to a VF page - they probably can't run it and could be deleted.

These aren't pixel-perfect, SF confirmed to me that Optimizer looks only at certain standard objects & custom ones but not all (I had significant problems hidden in std object that isn't checked, had to pull info from SF backend manually) but it's a start.

In another question you wrote you don't have any developer tools (Eclipse IDE, VScode etc), just dev console. This will limit your ability to just search the project for references to class X... On VF pages "Where is this used" should help you a bit. There are some browser plugins you might want to check out (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-advanced-code/lnkgcmpjkkkeffambkllliefdpjdklmi) or there might be some SF plugins on AppExchange...

Where to start writing unit tests?  Heh :) Ideally business would be able to point you in general direction of functionality that most often changes / breaks / is most critical and therefore would benefit from nice harness of tests so maintenance developer won't break functionality.

Failing that you can choose to focus on top 10 classes that have most non-covered lines (attacking them should give you quickest coverage % gains). What I'm trying to say if you have class that has 60 / 100 lines covered by test and another that has 2 / 4 covered - it's better to attack the 1st one, even though it has higher coverage %. 
After running all tests in go to Developer Console -> Query Editor. On the bottom tick the checkbox for Tooling API. Query similar to this should be a good start:

```
SELECT ApexClassorTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered
FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate
ORDER BY NumLinesUncovered DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Is there any app available in App Exchange for achieving this?

Comment: Also, how to i give estimate for decommissioning unwanted code(any) and creating unit test cases?

Comment: I'm not aware of any app like that. SF improves these Optimizer reports so eventually apps like "Field Trip" might get merged / purchased by SF / obsolete. Deleting unused code is fairly easy but you'd need dev tools or at least Workbench. Google for "destructivechanges.xml". If it looks tricky - you can always use normal deplyment to update the class, set code to empty method names... Unit tests - really depends on how complex your business logic is. It's an investment that pays off during maintenance. If you don't have devs that could estimate - maybe some consulting company could eyeball?

Comment: Cross-post this to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ (and link to this question), you'll have better chance reaching admins, project managers... StackOverflow is more focused on "pure" code problems.